# Json.stringify allows HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to post values from MVC  view to controller.
Request validation feature is enabled for application.

But when i tried to pass values with HTML tags to controller, I am not getting any exception.

here is my ajax post:

```
       Group.Name = model.Name();
       Group.Id = model.ID();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: /IndexController/SaveGroup',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Group: group }),

            success: function (data /*, textStatus, request*/) {
                try {

                }
                catch (error) {
                    showExceptionWindow('Jquery Error:' + error);

                }
            },
            error: function (request /*, status, error*/) {
                handleException(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SaveGroup(Group group)
        {
```

when i tried to insert html tags,the values are passing to controller action method and getting saved.

When request validation feature is enabled,html elements should not be passed to controller.

How to make sure it is getting blocked at controller.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a typo as there `group` does not seem to be a valid object it is undefined:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ group: Group }), // <-----It should have to be this Group here
```

And at your backend:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveGroup(Group group) // group is {}
    {
```

---

Or as `Group` is already an object then you can stringify it directly:

```
data: JSON.stringify(Group), // <-----It should have to be this Group here

[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SaveGroup(Group Group) // group is {}
    {
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But my concern why the MVC validation is not happening and allowing HTML elements as Request validation feature is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

MVC validation dosent work since you've changed the submit button to prevent default mvc use the jquery plugin Validate.js just go through i,this code should work

```
var form = $("#YourFormID"); 
        form.validate();
        form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (form.valid()) {

              //Your ajax call

                 }  
        })
```

Comment: Even i tried to changed button type to "submit " but still validation is not occured

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an HTML parser to detect HTML elements injection? This can be a clean JS solution

```
var containsHTML = /<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test("<p>HTML text to be parsed</p>")
if(containsHTML==true){
    //There are HTML tags inside the string
}
else{
    //You're good to go
}
```